# Extract charcarters from a string

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create an little program where people could transform their name with chemical symbols (The Breaking bad way's).

I can get the two first letters, but I don't know how to get separately the rest of the letters:

```
puts "Please enter your name"
    name = gets.chomp
    first_letters = name[0,1]
    last_letters = name  - first_letters #I know it's wrong but here is the idea of what i want to do. Hope it's clear...
```

And then I will display the name with images corresponding to the first letters.

```
if first_letters.include? "br"
  puts "Br" + last_letters
end
if first_letters.include? "ba"
  puts "Ba" + last_letters
end
```

How can I isolate the last letters?

Thanks

Comment: Just a tip. In your code, the way you're getting `first_letters` looks wrong.
Using this code `name = 'Pablo'`, 
`first_letters = name[0,1]` returns only `P`.
 If you want to get the first two letters, use a `range`
`first_letters = name[0..1]` which returns `Pa`

Comment: @BlackEnigma O specify the correct length: `name[0,2]` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
name[2..-1]
```

or

```
name[2..name.length]
```

or if you want to go the regular expression way (no real need for that much complexity here)

```
match = name.match(/(.{2})(.*)/)
first_letters = match[1]
last_letters = match[2]
```

Now in all variants you might want to add some checking that the name has sufficient length.

Answer (score 0):

```
first, last = "String".scan(/\A(..)(.*)\z/).first 
#⇒ ["St", "ring"]
```

or simply:

```
first, last = "String".split(/(?<=\A..)/)
```

or, if you don’t yest know what the first letters is:

```
def get_rid_of_first(first)
  "String"[/(?<=\A#{Regexp.escape(first)}).*\z/]
end
get_rid_of_first("St")
#⇒ "ring"
```

Comment: will try this too !!